# 301 redirect: selective loss of extension within a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I am migrating a site, most pages have page to page 301 redirects - no problem.

There's a directory;
http://example.com/associates/
with a whole bunch of individual files; http://example.com/associates/first-last.php

I need to map them to  http://example.com/associates/first-last
I'm thinking `RewriteCond /associates/*\.php -f`
will find them, what will redirect them?

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 /associates/*.php(.*) /associates/*/$1`

Comment: You want to remove .php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
RedirectMatch ^/associates/([^.]+)\.php$ /associates/$1
```

([^.]+) captures any characters excluding a dot, in your case it will capture file name **first-last** and append it to target url as $1

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.

Time to do a bit of reading on redirects and regular expressions. 

Any hints for a tutorial?

Comment: You are welcome! You can learn more about url rewriting and url redirecting on official webpages of Apache, they explain how it works - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html 

also there are more other websites that teach about htaccess : htaccess-guide.com , javascriptkit.com also has a special section on url rewriting